# Android ProGuard with RoboGuice

Tags: android, proguard, roboguice

I am using RoboGuice in my android project.

I added the proguard rules as specified in the documentation:
https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/ProGuard

However, after I run the release apk, I get java.lang.NullPointerException crashes on views that were supposed to be injected vie RoboGuice.

I found somewhere that adding the following proguard rule for my views fixes that problem:

```
-keep class com.aaa.bbb.ui.fragments.* { *; }
```

However, I find it hard to believe that using RoboGuice means that I can't obfuscate my UI classes.

Is there another way to handle this problem?

Comment: hi dors, I'm in a similar situation, but I'm able to generate apk & run successfully by using the ProGuard rules from roboguice documentation.

Comment: Now I'm struggling to obfuscated my code. So when I { #-dontobfuscate }  I get bunch of error and apk is not generated.

Comment: Please can someone help me resolve this issue. thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/29278951/2291